# Workflow - Email 3rd Party after Approval

Tags: workflow

I have what I feel is a very straightforward requirement but I cannot figure out how to implement. The scenario is this:

- User A creates a supply order request.
- User B approves or rejects.
- User C also gets notified if the request is approved, as User C
  actually orders the supplies.

I have made a copy of the default Approval reusable workflow that I edited to send an email to User C in the approval step, but that does not give me any access to the underlying list item to include relevant details in the email.

Comment: For future reference, please tag/include which version of SharePoint you're using to help ensure answers are relevant to your SP Version

Answer (score 0):

You Can create SharePoint designer workflow , based on your requirement this should be a simple one, Assign a task and based on the task outcome you send email with related information.

below link should give a good idea on how you can achieve this: 
[How to create an Approval workflow using SharePoint designer](http://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-sharepoint-2013)